# C++ smart pointers with no std library

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

I'm a long time user of the `boost::smart_ptr` library and love it. Like all boost libraries it is design to work well with the C++ Standard Library. Which usually is a great thing.

*Unfortunately*, I'm facing a situation were I need to be *completely* independent of the standard library. Despite this I would need the same kind of functionality as that offered by the `boost::smart_ptr` (except, obviously every thing that has to do with std::). This includes amongst others, retain count, overloading of the bool and -> operators, relationships between `week_ptr` and `shared_ptr` etc.

Has anyone been faced with this situation? I'm looking into using the `boost::smart_ptr` as a starting point and replacing/eliminating `std::` related things. But looking at the complexity, am increasingly concerned about breaking things.

Comment: Just out of interest, why can't you use the std library. I'm curious to know when this would be a requirement

Comment: Do you want to be independent of boost, or of the standard library? Without the standard library, it isn't really C++ anymore.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can't use std or you can't use boost, or both?

Comment: The company I work for is converting a large database of audio/video related code (codec/renderers/dsp etc...) from c to c++. This code is currently running on a large number of platforms including many feature phones where the availability of std is not a given.

Comment: I can't use either std or boost (because it is highly dependent on std), but I need the functionality of smart pointers. C++ is a perfectly valid language without the std library, it's just that a lot of things need to be implemented from scratch witch is a pain.

Comment: If you are not using the std:: library then you may as well just leave the code as C (at least that is working). Re-inventing everything from scratch will just introduce bugs.

Comment: There is a huge c based OS abstraction layer in that code which dates back a long way (and uses hardly anything out of the box except malloc) and is running on over a billion devices, the switch to C++ is to provide more abstraction and oop, the people making the decisions are way above me.

Comment: @jbat100 - Send them a link to this page... ;-)

Comment: Make sure you have an automated test suite in place before you start re-factoring C to C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/index.php?n=Main.Download) library may help you, it has a SmartPtr class. It uses std (std::swap, std::runtime_error), but it does not seem to be too hard to get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll have a look at it!

Comment: Thanks, it's the closest to what I'm looking for, and clearly done by people who know what they are talking about...

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/).

This is an implementation of the C++ Standard Library with a liberal license (MIT or BSD-like) so that you can freely pick stuff out of it.

All the stream handling is very complicated (lot of locale stuff), however the STL part (containers and algorithms) as well as part of the numeric stuff (apart from formatting) could work out of the box.

If you need streams, it's a little more involved.

Finally, your biggest issue might come from the exception handling. Note that the Standard Library is normally supposed to work with exceptions enabled (`std::out_of_range` for example), and exception management is generally based on an external library (for example, see [libunwind](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/)). Of course, since you reimplement your own library, you can choose to `assert` instead of throwing.

I would seriously advise not using exceptions as it will be a major pain to make it work on all the devices you care about (it's a bit of a crippled C++ then, but you still get objects and templates).

Answer (score 0):

A classical in reference counting. Some basic code would look like this (shortest code I have managed to produce). Should be straightforward unless you know nothing about reference counting.

```
template <class CL>
struct refCount  {
    refCount() : nlinks_(1) , p_(0) {}
    refCount(CL*p) : nlinks_(1) , p_(p) {}
    ~refCount() { if (!nlinks_) delete p_;}
    size_t nlinks_;
    CL* p_;
    };

template <class CL>
class mySmartPtr {
public:
    mySmartPtr() : rc_(new refCount<CL>()) {}
    mySmartPtr(CL* p) : rc_(new refCount<CL>(p)) {}
    mySmartPtr(const mySmartPtr<CL> & otherSmartPtr) : rc_(otherSmartPtr.rc_) { rc_->nlinks_++ ;}
    mySmartPtr & operator=(const mySmartPtr<CL> & otherSmartPtr)        {
        otherSmartPtr.rc_->nlinks_++;
        if (!(-- rc_->nlinks_))  delete rc_;
        rc_ = otherSmartPtr.rc_; 
        return *this;}
    CL& operator *() {return * rc_->p_ ; }
    ~mySmartPtr() { if(!(--rc_->nlinks_)) delete rc_;}
// commented to print #links  (remove it)
// protected:
    refCount<CL> *rc_;
        };
```

A little (big) more work is needed if you need dynamic/static casts (thread safety).

Example of use:

```
int main()
{
 mySmartPtr<int> i;
 i = mySmartPtr<int>(new int(1));
 *i = 7;
 mySmartPtr<int> j(new int(3));
 j = i;
 std::cout << *j << std::endl ; // prints 7
 std::cout << i.rc_->nlinks_ << std::endl ; // prints 2, i and j point to the same
 {
  mySmartPtr<int> k(j);
  std::cout << i.rc_->nlinks_ << std::endl ; // prints 3, k points there two
 }
 std::cout << i.rc_->nlinks_ << std::endl ; // prints 2 , k gone out of scope

 return 0;
}
```